# Dual passport holder travel to Bali

Tags: customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, uk-citizens, australian-citizens, bali

I am a dual citizen with an in date UK passport and an Australian passport that has less than 6 months. I have applied for a new Australian Passport but it may not arrive before I am due to go to Bali next week.  Can I fly to Bali and return to Perth as and Australian Citizen on a UK passport?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel)

Comment: Yes, you can.  For the details, see the Q&A above.

Comment: For clarity, you should return to Australia on your Australian passport. If the airline gives you grief about the validity, show the airline the UK passport, but once landed in Perth, use only your Australian passport. If it's in date at that point, no issue whatsoever, if it's only slightly out of date, then you might get a few extra questions and may not be able to use automated gates (if they have them in Perth!)

Comment: @jpatokal How is this a duplicate? The question you link explains how Guy can travel with both his UK and Australian passports. But his Australian passport hasn't arrived yet and he's asking about travelling to Australia with _only_ his UK passport.

Comment: @Richard The Australian passport isn't in his possession because it's being renewed.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Renewing a passport in some countries does not necessitate surrendering the old one. It suggests here that the old passport is cancelled on submission at Australia Post, but not that it is taken from the holder: https://www.passports.gov.au/passports-explained/passport-renewal

Comment: My current Australian passport with less than 5 months until expiry is now void as the front cover was cut when I applied for the new one.

Comment: \*sigh\* I've already explained once why this isn't a duplicate, and now people are voting to close as a duplicate again.